# How can I echo first 3 entries of a table ( php)

Tags: php, mysql, select, echo

I have 4 entries in the table below.

[image]

I don't know how to select last 2/3 items from the table and echo them separately to use them in 3 divs like here :

```
<div class="entry1">here is the first entry</div>
<div class="entry2">here is the second entry</div>
<div class="entry3">here is the third entry</div>
```

I want them separately because of that differently div classes ...

Here is an example of the output(this should update by itself and take the entries Dynamically):

```
<div class="entry1">Category4</div>
<div class="entry2">Category3</div>
<div class="entry3">Category2</div>
```

Same goes for the first 3 entries ...

Comment: use order by autoincremt_id asc limit 3

Comment: This is basic SQL. Please go through some of the many tutorials on the Internet. We shouldn't be writing code for you.

Comment: Oh ... Sorry than but i really don't know how to split the last/first 3 records in 3 echos . In the next 10 minutes i will delete this post . Sorry for inconvenience...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM categories LIMIT 3
```

To get the first 3  entries:

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3
```

To get the 3 most recent entries:

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

This (naively) assumes your autoincrement primary key will keep rising forever. Add a `timestamp` field with default `current_timestamp` to make this totally idiotproof.

Comment: its not really a php answer, stricly the answer should be something like array_slice.. but always better to use the proper methods from the source. on top of that you shouldn't do SELECT * really

Comment: order by desc really?

Comment: @DarkMukke `SELECT *` isn't really wrong, it's just a convenience. In bigger systems you should select more specifically in most cases, but it serves the example.

Comment: @RakeshSharma what's wrong with that?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes yeh, i know what you mean, its not about wrong or not, it's about lazy coding or not, and personally i try to teach the world code in a non lazt matter

Comment: The question asks for *"the last 2/3 items"*. That's what I answer.

Comment: I think for the first 3 it's "asc" instead of desc (i understood) . But how i can select each one . If I use only this it will show me only : cat4,3,2 or cat1,2,3 and i can't use them in separate divs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 3 starting records then we will use below sql

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3
```

Above sql is your requirement

but if you want to get last 3 records from database table then we use it:

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```